# For $1\leq p<\infty$, $(l^p)^{\ast}\cong l^q$ for some $q$, and $(l^{\infty})^{\ast}\neq l^1.$

Tags: functional-analysis

We define
\begin{equation*}
l^p=\{(a_1, a_2, \cdots)\mid \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}|a_i|^p<\infty\}.
\end{equation*}

Then for $1\leq p<\infty$, $(l^p)^{\ast}\cong l^q$ for some $q$, and  $(l^{\infty})^{\ast}\neq l^1.$

How can I prove this? I tried to start by using uniform boundedness principle but couldn't go further.

Comment: You can find these proofs on-line and in many textbooks.  Why not look there, rather than asking here?

Answer (score 0):

The first question is "simply" the Riesz representation theorem. It has been discussed few times on this website.

To show that $(\ell^\infty(\mathbb{N}))^* \ne \ell^1 (\mathbb{N})$ it is enough to remember that if $X$ is a Banach space, then $X^*$ separable implies $X$ separable. Since $\ell^\infty$ is non separable, so is its dual. However $\ell^1$ *is* separable, therefore $(\ell^\infty(\mathbb{N}))^* = \ell^1 (\mathbb{N})$ can't hold.